# File Not Found error when accessing site settings through the Web versus server

Tags: central-administration, windows-server

We just installed Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 and SP2010 Enterprise.  The server is being hosted with a local company so we access it through remote desktop connection for now.  For some reason, if we try to access the site directly from the web instead of the server connection, we get a File Not Found error when accessing the Central Administration site settings.  This does not seem to happen with the SharePoint-80 application pool.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the firewall settings? If you do open up CA over the public internet you should really use SSL for the connection, otherwise security information may be passed in plain text. It might be easier to just continue using remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Zones or Alternate Access mappings maybe? What do the uls logs say?

Can you give me an example of the url you are hitting in each case (let's pretend your company is called Contoso).

That said, I am inclined to agree with SPDoctor and say that you shouldn't access CA over the Internet as a general principle.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestions- we're looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured DisableLoopbackCheck within the registry? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642/en-us

Comment: Thanks for the advice..just found out a few days ago that the person who installed Enterprise installed one application pool on top of the other, so I guess it's obvious at this point we just need to reinstall in hopes of a much better result :)